# Idiomatic way to handle logged in / guest UI with Angular

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have a site where most of the pages are accessible with or without login, but while logged in there would be a sidenav for example.

What would be the idiomatic way to handle this?

1. Creating two separate template/controller
2. Same template/controller with ng-if/ng-show
3. Any better idea maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate template, because either way you will need some kind of `ng-if/ng-show` to either include the template or not depending on if the user is logged in or not.

Having your sidebar in a separate directive or template makes sense just to keep your code modular, but you don't have to do it for what you're trying to do.

I typically will do something like:

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar" ng-show="isLoggedIn()">

</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller([
  'authenticationService',
  function(authenticationService) {
      $scope.isLoggedIn = function() {
          return authenticationService.isLoggedIn();
      };
  }
]);
```

Or you could do this using a directive like:

```
angular.module('app').directive('isVisibleToCurrentUser', [
  'authenticationService',
  function(authenticationService) {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function(scope, element) {
         if(authenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
           element.show();
         } else {
           element.hide();
         }

         authenticationService.on('loggedOut, function() {
           element.hide();
         });
       }
    };
  }
]);
```

The benefit of the directive is that all the logic about whether a user can see the element or not is encapsulated in the directive. Though this requires some kind of event like `authenticationService.on('loggedOut')` to know when to hide the element.

Comment: Yeah, I've been doing kinda the same so far, I'm just curious if there is a better way of handling this issue.

Comment: @officert i would at least wrap it in `ng-if` as it will remove the template from result thus not wasting parsing time.

Comment: @Andrew I updated my answer to include the option of putting all the logic about whether or not the user can see the sidebar into a directive. This is another alternative that has it's own pros and cons.